# Relay servlet (servlet calls another servlet)

Tags: java, servlets

Hello i have a question about servlet calling another servlet

I have a main servlet called Relay which is going to be responsible to control the other servlets

the user will click on and will be forwarded to Relay servlet

```
<li><a href="/oosd/Relay?selectAnimal=SelectAnimalServlet">Check the available animals</a> </li>
```

inside Relay servlet will get the value of the parameter to determine which servlet is going to run

```
String selectAnimal = request.getParameter("selectAnimal");

if (selectAnimal.equals("SelectAnimalServlet")){
            getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("/SelectAnimalServlet") 
            .forward(request, response); 
            //for testing
            System.out.println("Request forwarded to " + selectAnimal + " servlet");
        }
```

SelectAnimalServlet code:

```
try
{     
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser");
    List<AnimalSelectBean> beans = DAO.getAnimalList(); 
    request.setAttribute("beans", beans); 
    request.getRequestDispatcher("CheckAnimal.jsp").forward(request, response); 


}
```

Now when i run that it's not working for some reason, if i change the link to SelectAnimalServlet directly the code works any idea how to solve this ?

Edit:

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>content.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UpdateAnimalServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>content.UpdateAnimalServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SelectAnimalServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>content.SelectAnimalServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Relay</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>content.Relay</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SelectAnimalServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SelectAnimalServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UpdateAnimalServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UpdateAnimalServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Relay</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Relay</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

also I changed:

```
getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("/SelectAnimalServlet") 
                .forward(request, response);
```

to:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(selectAnimal));
```

and still the same thing blank webpage with http://localhost:8080/oosd/Relay?selectAnimal=SelectAnimalServlet link

Comment: By "not working", what do you mean? (And why are you doing this?)

Comment: not working means a blank white page, and i have to do this according to my coursework i have to create a relay servlet that controls other servler

Comment: i can do it by creating many forms and buttons with inserting a hidden input to pass the value instead of href links but i think there should be a way to go around this

Comment: Is there anything in the server log?

Comment: I'm getting this java.lang.NullPointerException

no idea if it relate to anything usefull or not

However the link in the page is 

http://localhost:8080/oosd/Relay?selectAnimal=SelectAnimalServlet

it should be http://localhost:8080/oosd/SelectAnimalServlet

I think the problem in directing from first servlet Relay to the second SelectAnimalServlet

Comment: You're not redirecting, you're forwarding--the URL won't change. Debug/log to find out what's null. Also, include your web.xml in the question; what's the name of the `SelectAnimalServlet`? I suspect you're using a name dispatcher when you should be using a `getRequestDispatcher("...")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getNamedDispatcher` expects a servlet name; you're providing it with a servlet URL.

Either use the name, or use `getRequestDispatcher` with the URL.

Since you're forwarding, the URL will not change--there is no redirect response sent back to the browser on a forward. The contents of the forward are written directly to the original response.

Now that you're forwarding, you need to redirect to the URL, not just the name of the servlet.

What does the servlet you redirect to do for output?

I don't believe your parameter naming convention makes any sense. The parameter shouldn't be named the same as a servlet name; the parameter should be something like "command" or "select". You would then use the command parameter value to look up the URL of the servlet. Or, in your case, just prepend a `/`, and you're done. There's no need to do any `if/else` comparisons.

Comment: You mean like this:
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("localhost:8080/oosd/SelectAnimalServlet");
   rd.forward(request, response);

or this:

getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("SelectAnimalServlet")  
            .forward(request, response);  


because both not working

Comment: @user1031152 Then you need to start adding some logging to figure out why.

Comment: @user1031152 Just use `System.out.println` for now; it will show up in the server logs. Are you using Tomcat, or...?

Comment: @user1031152 Does the servlet you're redirecting to create any output? This is all working for me without any issues.

Comment: yes SelectAnimalServlet will display records from database table and i don't know how to find the logs i'm new to this

Comment: @user1031152 In the tomcat installation's `logs` directory. In any case, [here's a working sanity check skeleton.](https://github.com/davelnewton/relay_servlet)

Comment: Now it's working! THANKS ALOT!!!!! finally i can stop banging my head to the table ^^ agian thanks alot

Comment: @user1031152 Awesome :) It's frustrating sometimes; we've all been there. What did the problem end up being?

Comment: i just replaced my crappy code with yours becasue i think using 1 name as command as you suggested is bettet than having many names
however, i still got the login as the same it's like this if (command.equals("LoginServlet")){ 
   String username =request.getParameter("username");
   String password =request.getParameter("password");
   
   RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("/"+command);
   rd.forward(request, response);
            //for testing 
            System.out.println("Request forwarded to " + command + " servlet"); 
        }  because i need to pass the values

Comment: @user1031152 Hmm, I mostly just copied your code ;) Yep, you'd need to handle servlet-specific stuff like you're doing, although there are some other options besides `if` statements. That's another day.

Comment: yeah i'm glad i'm done from the login/select stage still have update/delete/insert and thats it